# SQL statement did not return actual result

Tags: vb.net

I have written this code using vb.net but it give me wrong result.

```
 sql = "SELECT * FROM Spec WHERE WheatType= '" & ddlType.SelectedValue & "' AND Category='1BK' AND Silo= '" & txtSilo.Text & "'"
```

If i remove `Silo= '" & txtSilo.Text & "'` it give me the result but it not want i want. any idea how to fix it?

Comment: what's the "wrong" result? What's the "right" result? what's your table structure?

Comment: also potentially sql injectable

Comment: Check your `txtSilo.Text`. Have it desired text? And is `Silo` string type?

Comment: You should use Parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx  your query can easely be "hacked"

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess but your doing a case sensitive match there. Could be your txtSilo.Text is set to say "Red" and the row in the database has Silo set as say "red"

You could instead do

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Spec WHERE WheatType= '" & ddlType.SelectedValue & "' AND Category='1BK' AND Silo LIKE '" & txtSilo.Text & "'"
```

Keep in mind you should also perhaps trim the whitespace off the Textfield.

BTW this sort of code is very open to SQL injection attack... I would recommend reading up on that topic and fixing this major security hole if this is going to be a production app. Otherwise someone could say delete all rows on the table with the right value passed into txtSilo, etc.